# Creating a new array without duplicate integers from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I was asked to create a new array without duplicate integars from an array.

I think I made a mistake in my code but can't notice anything wrong.

The output for "1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4" is "1, 2, 2, 4".

It's supposed to be "1, 2, 4"

Would like to learn about my mistake.

```
    // Exercise 2 - 
void Ex2() {
    int i, counter = 1, size = -1;
    int* array = input_dynamic_array(&size);
    int* newArr = (int*)malloc((size)* sizeof(int));
    newArr[0] = array[0];
    assert(array);
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (!find_num_in_newArr(newArr, size, array[i])) {
            newArr[counter++] = array[i];
        }
    }
    newArr = (int*)realloc(newArr, (counter)*sizeof(int));
    printArray(newArr, counter);
    free(array);
    free(newArr);
}

bool find_num_in_newArr(int *newArr, int size, int num) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (newArr[i] == num) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

int* input_dynamic_array(int *size)
{
    int *array;
    int ii;
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", size);
    array = (int*)malloc((*size) * sizeof(int));
    assert(array);
    printf("Enter %d integer numbers: ", *size);
    for (ii = 0; ii < *size; ii++)
        scanf("%d", array + ii);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: the `for` loop in `find_num_in_newArr()` checks for `i < size-1`. Shouldnt it be `i < size` ?

Comment: Yes, noticed it and fixed it earlier, but still doesn't work, thanks

Comment: `return false` should be place after the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- `find_num_in_newArr` exits the loop with a `return false;` at the first iteration. move the `return` statement outside the loop body.
- `Ex2` check the whole array for duplicates instead of just the portion already copied: `find_num_in_newArr(newArr, size, array[i])` should be `find_num_in_newArr(newArr, i, array[i])`. As posted, this code has undefined behavior.

Here is a corrected version with a few extra assertions:

```
// Exercise 2 - 
bool find_num_in_newArr(const int *newArr, int size, int num) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (newArr[i] == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int *input_dynamic_array(int *size) {
    int *array;
    int ii;
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    assert(scanf("%d", size) == 1);
    assert(*size > 0);
    array = (int*)malloc((*size) * sizeof(int));
    assert(array != NULL);
    printf("Enter %d integer numbers: ", *size);
    for (ii = 0; ii < *size; ii++) {
        assert(scanf("%d", array + ii) == 1);
    }
    return array;
}

void Ex2(void) {
    int i, counter, size;
    int *array = input_dynamic_array(&size);
    int *newArr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    assert(newArr != NULL);
    newArr[0] = array[0];
    counter = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (!find_num_in_newArr(newArr, i, array[i])) {
            newArr[counter++] = array[i];
        }
    }
    newArr = (int*)realloc(newArr, counter * sizeof(int));
    assert(newArr != NULL);
    printArray(newArr, counter);
    free(array);
    free(newArr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I see a problem here:

```
for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++) 
{
    if (newArr[i] == num) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will never have another iteration. It will either return `true` or `false` from the first iteration. Thats not what you are planning for when you used a loop.

Based on your design, you might want to move `return false;` outside the loop.

Another advise, [Don't cast the return value of `malloc`, its pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/4228131).

Also,

```
int* newArr = (int*)malloc((size)* sizeof(int));
```

This needs to be followed by a check. You need to check if `malloc` returned `NULL`. If yes, then memory is not allocated and anything with modification based on `newArr` would be horrible.

A relative cleaner way of doing it will include using a function that looks like below:

```
int RemoveDuplicates(int* Arr, int length)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int LengthChanged = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < LengthChanged ; j++)
        {
            if(Arr[i] == Arr[j])
                break;
        }

        // Copy as is if there is not duplicate element in the array
        if (j == LengthChanged )
            Arr[LengthChanged++] = Arr[i];
    }

    return LengthChanged;
}
```

Comment: There is another problem in `Ex2` that will prevent correct operation.

Comment: @chqrlie: Ah, I did see your answer covering that. To be honest I did't catch it, and it would be unfair to merely copy that up from your answer into mine. So I have already upvoted your answer, and its good that OP has marked yours as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You over complicate it a bit.
Use the correct types for the indexes (`size_t`)

```
int CheckValue(int *arr, int value, size_t size)
{
    while (size--)
    {
        if (arr[size - 1] == value) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,4,5,8,3,2,1,-1,9,-1,-1,6,8,1,5,4,2,3};
    int newarr[sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])];
    size_t size = 0;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); index++)
    {
        if (!CheckValue(newarr, arr[index], size))
        {
            newarr[size++] = arr[index];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```